# Why is my react-query fetching the data from the previous search?

Tags: react-hook-form, react-typescript, react-query

On `console.log(data?.data)`, it is returning the data from the previous search. So if I enter "house" on my initial search it will return as if I entered an empty string, and then the next time I click search it will return as if I entered "house". I suspect there is some staling issue happening but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import { Stack, TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useState } from "react";

interface FormValues {
  tvSearch: string;
}
interface Tv {
  id: number;
}
interface ShowData {
  data: Tv[];
}

function ShowBox() {
  const [tvSearchQuery, setTvSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const form = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      tvSearch: "",
    },
  });
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = form;
  const { errors } = formState;

  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv",
    params: {
      query: tvSearchQuery,
      include_adult: "false",
      language: "en-US",
      page: "1",
    },
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      Authorization:
        "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJmNzNkMDE0YzkzNDQ5OTQxNThkZjNlNWQ0MWVjZGY1NCIsInN1YiI6IjY0ZTQ2NzlhMWZlYWMxMDBjNDZjMWUyNCIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.quqnVGOyEV10UKyr4PCb39i6JpkdKtvX4kDSoIq9gss",
    },
  };
  console.log(tvSearchQuery);
  function onSubmit(data: FormValues) {
    setTvSearchQuery(data.tvSearch);
    refetch();
  }
  function fetchTvData(): Promise<void | ShowData> {
    return axios.request(options);
  }
  function onSuccess(data: object) {
    console.log("success", data);
  }
  function onError(error: Error) {
    console.log("ERROR", error);
  }
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: "tv-results",
    queryFn: fetchTvData,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    enabled: false,
    onSuccess,
    onError,
  });
  console.log(data?.data);
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
      <Stack spacing={2}>
        <TextField
          label="Enter a show or movie"
          type="tvSearch"
          {...register("tvSearch")}
          error={!!errors.tvSearch}
          helperText={errors.tvSearch?.message}
        />
        <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
          Search
        </Button>
      </Stack>
    </form>
  );
}

export default ShowBox;
```

Answer (score 1):

because your search value is not part of the QueryKey. From [the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key):

> If your query function depends on a variable, include it in your query key
> Since query keys uniquely describe the data they are fetching, they should include any variables you use in your query function that change. For example:

```
function Todos({ todoId }) {
  const result = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['todos', todoId],
    queryFn: () => fetchTodoById(todoId),
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm still a little confused on how to implement this with the  "options" object.  I tried adding the "tvSearchQuery" state variable in the query key but that didn't seem to have any effect.